# Add Progress Bar with Progress to File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am redesigning an app and I am trying to get a bootstrap progress bar to show the percentage of the upload progress instead of the gif that just says "please wait".

I think I need to add an Event Listener but I'm not very familiar with JavaScript/JQuery.  Can you help me with what I need to add to get the end result I want?

This is my View.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Async file upload</h2>
<form action="/api/FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="uploadControls">
        <div>
            <span>Select file(s) to upload :</span>
            <input id="fileUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="btnUpload" type="button" value="Upload" />
        </div>
        <ul id="uploadResults">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="uploadProgress" class="hidden">
        <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnUpload").click(OnUpload);
    });

    function ShowUploadControls() {
        $("#uploadControls").show();
        $("#uploadProgress").hide();
    }
    function ShowUploadProgress() {
        $("#uploadControls").hide();
        $("#uploadProgress").show();
    }

    function OnUpload(evt) {
        var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {

            ShowUploadProgress();

            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/FileUpload",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (results) {
                        ShowUploadControls();
                        $("#uploadResults").empty();
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            $("#uploadResults").append($("<li/>").text(results[i]));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        ShowUploadControls();
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 multiple file uploads! Please use some decent browser.");
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: This is where i use a plugin. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I'd like to not have to rely on any Plugins, and also to learn the language so i can reuse my knowledge on other projects and maybe one day answer someone's question on here.

Comment: Here's an example on how to do it: http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-progress-bar-for-php-ajax-file-upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to get the Progress bar and still have the controller do the work for uploading the file.

In the Head I included these scripts

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then the body of the form and the scripts.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Name:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" required placeholder="John Smith">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Email:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="test@test.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Company:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required placeholder="Test Company, Inc">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB):</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="sbmtBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <br />
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar">0%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

    <script>
        (function () {
            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var percent = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    status.html("Please Wait While We Upload Your File(s)");
                    var percentValue = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentValue = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                },
                success: function (d) {
                    var percentValue = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                    $('#fu1').val('');
                    status.empty();
                    alert(d);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html("You can Upload again or close this page.");
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
```